# How to copy boolean column information on pandas dataframe to another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
ColA    ColB    Code    Value
FALSE   FALSE   J060    FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   J010    FALSE
FALSE   TRUE    J030    TRUE    
FALSE   FALSE   J111    FALSE
TRUE    TRUE    Z290    FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   B340    TRUE
TRUE    FALSE   B340    FALSE
FALSE   TRUE    B340    FALSE
```

Columns ColA, ColB and Value are boolean columns. I want to create a new dataframe with the same number of rows, such that the information of the boolean columns are converted into strings:

```
Code    BooleanInformation
J060    
J010    
J030    ColB,Value
J111    
Z290    ColA,ColB
B340    Value
B340    ColA
B340    ColB
```

Code column should remain unaltered. When a TRUE value occur in the first dataframe, the column name (ColA, ColB or Value) should be inserted into the string on the second dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for index from `Code` column, then [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with matric multiplication by all columns without `Code` and separator, remove separator and convert Series to `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Code')
         .dot(df.columns.drop('Code') + ',')
         .str[:-1]
         .reset_index(name='BooleanInformation'))
```

Alternative with select only boolean columns:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Code')
         .dot(df.select_dtypes(bool).columns + ',')
         .str[:-1]
         .reset_index(name='BooleanInformation'))
```

---

```
   Code BooleanInformation
0  J060                   
1  J010                   
2  J030         ColB,Value
3  J111                   
4  Z290          ColA,ColB
5  B340              Value
6  B340               ColA
7  B340               ColB
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.txt')

df[['ColA', 'ColB', 'Value']].astype(bool)

df['BooleanInformation'] = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join([column for column in df.columns if row[column] and column !='Code']), axis=1)

df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,3]], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```